# Is something wrong with my $PROFILE environment variable?

Tags: powershell, windows-10, profile

If I execute

```
& $PROFILE
```

I get this error

```
& : The term 'C:\Users\stib\Documents\WindowsPowerShell\
Microsoft.PowerShell_profile.ps1' is not recognized as the name of a cmdlet,
function, script file, or operable program. Check the spelling of the name,
or if a path was included, verify that the path is correct and try again.
At line:1 char:3
+ & $PROFILE
+   ~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : ObjectNotFound: (C:\Users\stib...ell_profile.ps1:String) [], CommandNotFoundException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : CommandNotFoundException
```

The correct profile is found at `$PROFILE.CurrentUserAllHosts`. Is there something wrong with my setup?

Comment: Go to `C:\Users\stib\Documents\WindowsPowerShell` I am sure you will find that you don't have a `Microsoft.PowerShell_profile.ps1`

Comment: What Drew said. Run `& $PROFILE.CurrentUserAllHosts` if that's what you actually want executed. That shouldn't be necessary, though, b/c PowerShell should automatically load the relevant [profiles](https://blogs.technet.microsoft.com/heyscriptingguy/2012/05/21/understanding-the-six-powershell-profiles/) upon launch.

Comment: Yep, when I start a PS Session my profile is loaded correctly, I was just wondering if I'd misconfigured something (as I am wont to do).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The reason for this behavior is the default selection for `$Profile.ToString()` that gets called when you invoke it using the `&` operator (which is `$Profile.CurrentUserCurrentHost`).

Selectively execute your profiles instead of relying on defaults:

```
& $Profile.CurrentUserAllHosts
```

---

As a footnote, `$Profile` is just an extended `System.String` with added properties and a modified `ToString` method.  See:

```
$Profile | Get-Member -MemberType NoteProperty
```

Additionally, the profiles that apply to your current shell are automatically executed when you launch that shell unless `-NoProfile` is passed to the executable.

Answer (score 1):

I ran into this issue when setting oh-my-posh up because of the way my work computers are configured.

I just created the file that was missing and then everything worked OK.